# How to use VBA excel macros for font style in a same cell of an Excel document

Tags: excel, vba

Could anyone please help me in the below objective:

Need to make the font as bold as shown below .

**Highlights for current week:**
Rollout/ACPT/Live Defect Retesting is in progress

The above text will be displayed in a same cell of an excel document.

```
Sub FetchData()

ThisWorkbook.Save
strWorkFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TEP WSR Dashboard.xlsm"
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Visible = False
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strWorkFileName)

introwcount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 5 To introwcount
   strProject = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 2).Value)
   On Error Resume Next
   Set objWorkSheet = objWorkbook.Sheets("" & strProject & "")
   If Not objWorkSheet Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 5).Value = Trim(objWorkSheet.Cells(12, 6).Value)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 6).Value = "Reason for Amber/Red:" + Chr(10) + Trim(objWorkSheet.Cells(32, 2).Value) + Chr(10) + Chr(10) + "Mitigation Plan:" + Chr(10) + Trim(objWorkSheet.Cells(37, 2).Value) + Chr(10) + Chr(10) + "Highlights for current week:" + Chr(10) + Trim(objWorkSheet.Cells(22, 2).Value) + Chr(10) + Chr(10) + "Action Plan for next Week:" + Chr(10) + Trim(objWorkSheet.Cells(27, 2).Value)
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 5).Value = "AMBER" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 5).Value = "GREEN" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 5).Value = "RED" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed").Cells(i, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
    Set objWorkSheet = Nothing
Next

ThisWorkbook.Save
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit


Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub
```

In the above script I need to make the font of "Action planned for next week" as bold and underline
 Could you please help here

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274038/change-only-a-specific-part-of-a-string-in-a-cell-keep-rest-as-it-is

Comment: Sorry i am not getting any clue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this example then you should be able to change your code as you need:

```
Sub Makro1()
    Range("A1").Select
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=28).Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .FontStyle = "bold"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
End Sub
```